# How do I build a form for creating a post that belongs to a user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Im a rails beginner on rails 4 and I'm learning by doing. I have users and posts on my simple test app. My user model

```
has_many :posts
```

My post model

```
belongs_to :user
```

I have a form partial for creating a new post like this

```
<%= form_for @post do |f| %>
<% if @post.errors.any? %>
    <ul>
        <% @post.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
            <li><%= msg %></li>
        <% end %>
    </ul>
<% end %>
<%= f.label :title %>
<%= f.text_field :title %>
<br/>
<%= f.label :body %>
<%= f.text_area :body %>
<br/>
<%= f.submit %>
```

My routes file

```
resources :users do
  resources :posts, except: [:index]
end
```

When i try to create a new post, I get a

**No route matches [POST] "/posts"**

Im assuming that its not working because of how my form partial is set up. I think that the

```
form_for @post do |f|
```

needs to be different, but I'm not sure what to change it to. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: It should be something like `form_for [@user, @post] do |f|`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for this route

```
resources :users do
  resources :posts, except: [:index]
end
```

You must create form with

```
form_for [@user, @post] do |f|
```

or

```
form_for [current_user, @post] do |f|
```

Comment: Thanks, that was it. I used the [current_user, @post] and its working. Now I need to figure out how to print the name of the user that posted it.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the `except: [:index]` from the route. That must block /posts access.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have the except, [:index] in there so I can view all the posts in the app regardless of the user that posted them. I have it redefined as resources :posts, only [:index] later, but I kept that out of this question for brevity.

Comment: @oobie11 Run `rake routes`. Do you see something like `/posts`? It should be `users/:id/posts` instead. And also you need to remove `except` part.

Comment: Your link for "index" is "GET /posts". And for the "create" is "POST /posts". I think if you are blocking index, so the create will be blocked too and you created form won't work.